# How can I make object properties with certain depth always be visible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, nestjs, aws-elasticsearch

I'm working on a project with Nest.js where I have to make a query object like this with my dynamic filter builder. I encountered a problem where I have to make an object with some depth to send it as part of the query to an external API.
All the '2nd level' properties are visible..(the object inside the object),
but all the '3rd level' properties are shown as [Object] or [Array].

```
//my completed filter

    const filterArr = [
        { match: { platform: 'INSTAGRAM' } },
        { match: { grade: 'CELL' } },
        { match: { gender: 'FEMALE' } },
        { match: { follower: [Object] } }
    ]

//my place holding query

    let query = {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: null,
        },
      },
    };

//and I add my filterArr to my place holding query like this:

    query.query.bool.must = filterArr;

//and my result is this
{ query: { bool: { must: [Array] } } }
```

When I try to take that object to make a search query to elasticsearch, it does not let me do it and returns me this:

```
/// just replaced some private info with ...

[Nest] 261066  - 2023. 06. 19. 오후 11:08:40   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Request failed with status code 400
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
    at settle (/home/.../Desktop/.../.../node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (/home/.../Desktop/.../.../node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:570:11)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

What I expect to see is

```
[
  { match: { platform: 'INSTAGRAM' } },
  { match: { grade: 'CELL' } },
  { match: { gender: 'FEMALE' } },
  { match: { follower: { gte: 0, lte: 1000 } }
]
```

inside my query instead of [Array].

I tried making my query object into string since I use JSON.stringify(query) to send the actual request.

This is the filterBuilder I made

```
    filterBuilder = (
        platform?: string,
        grade?: string,
        gender?: string,
        gte?: number,
        lte?: number,
    ) => {

    let filterArr = [];

    if (platform) {
        let block = { match: { platform } };
        filterArr.push(block);
    }
    if (grade) {
        let block = { match: { grade } };
        filterArr.push(block);
    }
    if (gender) {
        let block = { match: { gender } };
        filterArr.push(block);
    }
    if (gte !== undefined && lte !== undefined) {
        let block = { match: { follower: { gte, lte } } };
        filterArr.push(block);
    }
    console.log(filterArr);
    return filterArr;
    };
```

I did some searching and I'm not exactly sure about the terminology of my issue.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: The `400` error, and the fact that `console.log` chooses not to print the entire array are 2 separate issues. Your expected result is there, it's just not printed entirely. Also where do you use `filterBuilder`? You declared it but didn't show where it is actually called.

Comment: @CoderApprentice so I'm making a 'dynamic' filter where the value inside the filter changes depending on what query string i receive. And for the error message I thought that because even console.log was not showing the actual values inside the object, the data in the axios request wasn't getting sent properly.. thus getting the 400 error

Comment: @InseokChang `console.log(JSON.stringify(filterArray))` should do the trick to print all nested stuff. As for the 400, I don't know whats going wrong there yet :) might check later when i have more time